# Parallel.ForEach Error when using WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient, parallel.foreach

First, my disclaimer: I'm a parallel noob. I thought this would be an easy "embarrassingly parallel" problem to tackle, but it's thrown me for a loop.

I'm trying to download some photos in parallel from the web. The original photos are Hi-Res and take up quite a bit of space, so I'm going to compact them once they're downloaded.

Here's the code:

```
    private static void DownloadPhotos(ISet<MyPhoto> photos)
    {
        List<MyPhoto> failed = new List<MyPhoto>();

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string folderDayOfYear = now.DayOfYear.ToString();
        string folderYear = now.Year.ToString();
        string imagesFolder = string.Format("{0}{1}\\{2}\\", ImagePath, folderYear, folderDayOfYear);

        if (!Directory.Exists(imagesFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(imagesFolder);
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(photos, photo =>
        {
            if (!SavePhotoFile(photo.Url, photo.Duid + ".jpg", imagesFolder))
            {
                failed.Add(photo);
                Console.WriteLine("adding to failed photos: {0} ", photo.Duid.ToString());
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("failed photos count: {0}", failed.Count);

        RemoveHiResPhotos(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}\{2}", ImagePath, folderYear, folderDayOfYear));
    }


    private static bool SavePhotoFile(string url, string fileName, string imagesFolder)
    {
        string fullFileName = imagesFolder + fileName;
        string originalFileName = fileName.Replace(".jpg", "-original.jpg");
        string fullOriginalFileName = imagesFolder + originalFileName;

        if (!File.Exists(fullFileName))
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFile(url, fullOriginalFileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("failed to download photo: {0}", fileName);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            CreateStandardResImage(fullOriginalFileName, fullOriginalFileName.Replace("-original.jpg", ".jpg"));
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void CreateStandardResImage(string hiResFileName, string stdResFileName)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(hiResFileName);
        Image newImage = image.Resize(1024, 640);
        newImage.SaveAs(hiResFileName, stdResFileName, 70, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

So here's where things confuse me: each of the photos hits the Catch{} block of the SavePhotoFile() method at the `webClient.DownloadFile` line. The error message is an exception occured during a WebClient request and the inner detail is "The process cannot access the file . . . -original.jpg because it is being used by another process."

If I wasn't confused enough by this error, I'm confused even more by what happens next. It turns out that if I just ignore the message and wait, the image will eventually download and be processed.

What's going on?

Comment: What is Duid?  I assume since it's being passed into the fileName parameter it is the filename and unique?  Also, does the number of exceptions equal the number of files in the list?

Comment: It's a guid that identifies the file.

Comment: No, by visually watching the output folder, if the photo files are small enough that they load quickly, then those don't get added to the errors count.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx): _The body delegate is invoked once for each element in the source enumerable. It is provided with the current element as a parameter._  One thing you could try is adding a random number to the filename when you save it.  This way you can see 1) how many of each file there is and 2) if for some reason the Duid is not as unique as you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it appears in my focus on parallelism that I made a simple error: I assumed something about my data that wasn't true. Brianestey figured out the problem: Duid isn't unique. It's supposed to be unique, except for some missing code in the process to create the list.

The fix was to add this to the MyPhoto class

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is MyPhoto)
        {
            var objPhoto = obj as MyPhoto;
            if (objPhoto.Duid == this.Duid)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Duid.GetHashCode();
    }
```